# React native 0.29 async throws `unexpected token` exception

Tags: react-native

I am using RN 0.29, which should support `async` call natively. I tried using the [example from RN docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.29/docs/network.html#using-fetch):

```
async getMoviesFromApi() {
  try {
    let response = await fetch('http://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json');
    let responseJson = await response.json();
    return responseJson.movies;
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

But I got an error:

> SyntaxError /path/to/file.js: Unexpected token

I tried googling but it seems to be working fine for everyone else so I am a bit clueless here... I don't have any `babelrc` or any special packages.

The weird thing is that if I add `function` it works fine:

```
async function getMoviesFromApi() {
  ...
```

But none of the RN example I saw online had the `function` keywork.

What might cause this discrepancy?

Comment: You were probably seeing an object or class literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To declare a function, you do need the `function` keyword.

You were looking at an object or class literal, where you don't.